# Comment traduire « geek » en français ?

Tags: traduction, anglais

Quel serait le mot français qui traduirait le plus fidèlement le mot *geek* ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Il n'y en a a priori aucun qui soit tout-à-fait satisfaisant, car le mot est apparu tel quel sur Internet, même chez les francophones.

On pourrait proposer **passionné** ou **technophile**, mais chacun ne sera peut-être pas adapté à tous les contextes.

On peut éventuellement chercher d'autres pistes de traduction dans les définitions de [la page wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geek) ou du plus traditionnel (quoique, ici, très concis) [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/geek/10910404). (il y en a beaucoup d'autres, de qualité très variable, vu la popularité du terme, une recherche google permettra de s'en convaincre)

Comment: Un geek n'est pas un passioné. Un geek c'est un informaticien. Une personne calée en informatique. Votre réponse me semble erronée...on peut être technophile et pas calé. En tout cas, a geek de n'importe quoi c'est une personne qui sait faire la chose en question.

Comment: Je ne suis pas convaincu que "geek" fasse exclusivement référence a l'informatique, quoique c'est probablement le plus courant. Je rapprocherais ce mot de "otaku" en Japonais, mais la encore, les connotations sont une fois de plus différentes.

Comment: @Lambie Être geek ne fait état que d'une passion. Il n'y pas besoin d'être calé en quoi que ce soit - le fait qu'un geek soit calé en quelque chose n'est pas nécessaire, c'est surtout un abus de langage à la base. On peut très bien par exemple être un *geek* en appareils photos, i.e. on suit toutes les actualités/nouveautés liées à ce domaine sans pour autant savoir tous les réglages possibles liés à la photographie.

Comment: @Paul - méfiance, en suivant ce thread, je commence a avoir l'impression que les connotations du mot "geek", en fonction de l'endroit et du lieu. "Geek" pourrait aussi avoir une connotation uni-dimensionnelle: quelqu'un qui ne s'intéresse qu'aux gadgets électroniques, par exemple.

Comment: @Frank Certes, mais le côté informatique est dû majoritairement au fait que c'est là que ça a été popularisé. En anglais, on peut dire par exemple qu'on est un *music geek*, *theater geek*, etc.

Comment: Encore faudrait-il que tout le monde soit d'accord sur la définition anglophone de *geek* et sur la définition française du même mot, qui semble différente.

Answer (score 3):

Traductions compréhensibles par un néophyte, trouvées sur [linguee](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais?query=geek&source=english) :

Les **mordus d'informatique**,

et par transposition de l'utilisation du mot *geek* dans un autre contexte : 
les **fous d'informatique**, familièrement les  ***fondus d'informatiques***

Si cela renvoie à une personne moins jeune, plus professionnelle : 
les **experts passionnés d'informatique**  (dix consonnes au lieu d'une).

Comment: +1 J'aime assez *mordu d'informatique*, même s'il ne couvre pas tous les cas de *geek*. Cependant, une personne *moins jeune et plus professionnelle* sera-t-elle toujours, même passionnée d'informatique, un *geek* ? Je pressens le danger de voir ce débat partir en comparaison *geek* / *nerd*...

Comment: @RomainVALERI les anciens geeks deviennent souvent des chefs de service, des directeurs et autres cadres lorsqu'ils croient connaître tous les cotés techniques, ou lorsqu'ils sont entrés dans les projets industrialisés, normalisés qui augmentent le montant de leurs paies et les transforment en gestionnaires "bons à tout faire". Je pensais à l'espèce rare de ceux qui la cinquantaine passée, inventent encore de nouveau jeux, découvrent de nouvelles utilisations, ne peuvent s'empêcher d'être à la fois créatifs et à la pointe de leur domaine technique, maîtres de leurs langages et modèles.

Answer (score 1):

Beaucoup de gens, parmi les plus jeunes générations, disent simplement "geek", en fait.

"Mordu/passionné d'informatique" à mon avis ne couvre pas bien toutes les connotations du mot "geek". "Technophile" serait plus complet, mais une fois de plus, toutes les connotations n'y sont pas, et "-phile" est trop positif, alors que "geek", suivant les contextes, n'est plus forcément/entièrement positif.

Le mot "polard" pourrait plus ou mois correspondre a "geek", dans certains contextes.

Dans la Silicon Valley aujourd'hui, en particulier, "geek" pourrait avoir des connotations de futilité, manque d'intelligence sociale, inégalité sociale pour certains. Il peut être associé à "nerd" et même "dork" - qui est négatif (un collègue à qui j'ai demandé un synonyme, m'a immédiatement dit "dork" - évidemment un préjugé personnel, mais qui illustre bien les connotations de "geek").

Donc, un peu impossible à rendre correctement, surtout que les connotations peuvent évoluer en temps réel...

Comment: Oui, mais on peut être geek en n'importe quoi. Un calé de x. Dork et geek n'est pas un rapport. Un dork c'est dans la vie courante, pas spécialement pour la tecno. A dork is an asshole. But it's not as dirty.

Comment: 2 native English speakers I asked to came up with "dork" as their first synonym for "geek" - I was surprised - apparently because "dork" is not too dirty, and as connotations of "socially awkward". I only cite this to bring to illustrate the constellation of associations that people might have for the word "geek". For technology in particular, now they have "techie" here in Silicon Valley, which I was told is a straight insult.

Comment: So what? High schoolers call each other dorks all the time and it does not mean geek really. You asked them casually. A geek and dork are only similar in a non-techie context, very generically. You can be a surfing geek and a skiing geek too. But a dork who skies is an asshole who skies.  Dork is not TOO dirty but it does mean an asshole. He's a dork aka asshole. In Silicon Valley, they say it is an insult because they are all geeks (basically, coders en mal de fortune).

Comment: Who said that dork means geek? I'm only exploring connotations, and I guess my point is that connotations depend on time and place. No point arguing that this or that is the unique and precise meaning of "geek". It changes and depends on many things.

Comment: Frank, I am a native speaker of English. I am very aware of what the terms mean and how they are used. I am not arguing a unique and precise meaning of geek.

Comment: One of my points was that even among native speakers, there will be different connotations, and that it is changing too, even in a locale such as SV. IMHO, the best we can do is offer different possibilities, and look at the context. Translating one word in isolation is often near impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Le problème du français, c'est qu'il a perdu hélas sa capacité à créer de nouveaux concepts ou à réhabiliter des mots qui existent dans son patrimoine lexical. Le mot "geek" a été adopté par la plupart des internautes, il s'est imposé sous la pression de l'anglais et il est vain de vouloir a posteriori essayer de lui trouver un substitut. Cependant, si on fait un peu d'étymologie, on se rend compte que "geek" vient du moyen bas-allemand "geck" (du 12e siècle au 16e siècle) et du néerlandais "gek" (les deux mots signifiant "fou"). Ce mot a été francisé dans les dialectes du nord et de l'est de la France en "gicque" qui désigne "un fou de carnaval". Il suffirait donc de réhabiliter ce mot en lui octroyant une acception moderne en informatique et ferait parfaitement l'affaire pour remplacer "geek". J'en profite pour remercier nos amis canadiens qui sont beaucoup plus inventifs quand ils s'agit de contrecarrer les anglicismes: grâce à eux, nous pouvons dire "courriel" au lieu de "mail", "divulgacher" au lieu de "spoiler", "clavarder" au lieu de "chatter", "magasiner" au lieu de "faire du shopping", ... Tous ces mots sont à notre disposition. Il suffit de les utiliser et de les répandre sur la toile.
;-)

Answer (score 0):

En faisant quelques recherches sur la toile, je viens de constater que certains internautes suggèrent le mot « **mordi** » pour remplacer « **geek** ». Voilà une proposition qui me semble intéressante. Mais comment arrive-t-on à ce terme ? Il s'agit en fait de l'expression « **un mordu d'ordi** », grâce à laquelle on a pu créer le mot-valise : « **un mordi** ». Ça sonne bien en français ! Vous trouverez un des promoteurs de ce néologisme à l'adresse suivante : 
https://www.buzzfeed.com/fr/bullo/19-mots-quon-devrait-utiliser-plus-souvent-pour-remplacer-le